# jQuery issue related to function which seems to be firing twice - maybe needs unbinding?

Tags: jquery

Sorry if the title isn't actually relevant but I'm not sure where the issue lies exactly.

I've created a Codepen example to demonstrate the issue - and working example included below too.
https://codepen.io/justinchev/pen/ywNJqp

Desired functionality is that when you click a slide a 'detail' overlay appears for that slide. With the detail open you can scroll through the popup details for all slides using 'Previous' & ' Next' buttons.
Clicking 'Close' hides the detail overlay and you return to the slides.

Everything seems to work fine the first time you click a slide, ie you can click through the detail pages as expected, and clicking close works as expected.

The issue is that after you have clicked 'close' if you click on a slide the detail overlay appears again, but when clicking 'previous & next' the  detail pages don't appear as they should with prev & next clicks being fired twice.

Eg. Click slide 2 > click close > Click slide 1 > press next > you end up going to slide 3 rather than slide 2.

The problem is compounded every time you click close and reopen a slide detail, ie more detail overlays disappear.

Things I've considered might be the problem, and have tinkered with - they might actually be the issue so thought I'd mention.

- one() function might need to be unbound on clicking close, but according to the jQuery docs you can't unbind a one() function.
- something to do with how the the 'prevNextUpdate' function is being called.
- Maybe 'prevId' & 'nextId' variables need to be reset on clicking 'close'.

BTW the reason I'm using the jquery one() function is because the slides elements aren't available on initial page load as the carousel is generated with Slick Slider.

I'm aware the way I've achieved the functionality could probably be improved, but alas I'm no guru when it comes to jQuery/JS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jquery code below:

```js
$('body').one({mouseenter: function () {
  
  // set ID's on each slides
  $('.slide .showDetail').each(function() {
    var slideId = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).closest('.slide').addClass(slideId);
  });
  
  // show detail & nav buttons on slide click
  $('.slide .showDetail').click(function() {
    $('.slideButtons').show();
    
    // set active slide class
    var activeDetailId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.dir ("active Id: " + (activeDetailId));
    $(this).closest('.slide').addClass('activeSlide');
    
    // Show Solution detail
    $('.slideDetail.detail' + activeDetailId).show().addClass('activeDetail');
  
    //Prev & Next Id's - set as public var
    var prevNextUpdate = function(){

      this.prevId = $('.activeSlide').prev('.slide').find('.showDetail').attr('id');
      console.dir ("prev Id: " + (prevId));
      if (prevId == null) {
        $('.previous').hide();
      } else {
        $('.previous').show();
      } 

      this.nextId = $('.activeSlide').next('.slide').find('.showDetail').attr('id');
      console.dir ("next Id: " + (nextId));
      if (nextId == null) {
        $('.next').hide();
      } else {
        $('.next').show();
      }
    }
    prevNextUpdate();
    
    //Prev & Next click actions
    $('.previous').click(function() {
      $('.slideDetail.activeDetail').removeClass('activeDetail').hide();
      $('.slide.activeSlide').removeClass('activeSlide');
      $('.slideDetail.detail' + prevId).addClass('activeDetail').show();
      $('.slide.' + prevId).addClass('activeSlide');
      prevNextUpdate();
    });
    $('.next').click(function() {
      $('.slideDetail.activeDetail').removeClass('activeDetail').hide();
      $('.slide.activeSlide').removeClass('activeSlide');
      $('.slideDetail.detail' + nextId).addClass('activeDetail').show();
      $('.slide.' + nextId).addClass('activeSlide');
      prevNextUpdate();
    });
    
    // Close actions
    $('.close').click(function() {
      $('.slideButtons').hide();
      $('.slideDetail.activeDetail').removeClass('activeDetail').hide();
      $('.slide.activeSlide').removeClass('activeSlide');
      prevNextUpdate();
    });
    
    
  });
}}, ".slider");
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow:visible;
  width:480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;  
  background:#ccc;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.showDetail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.slideDetail {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #c00;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 35px;
}
.slideButtons {
  display:none;
  text-align:center;
}

.previous,
.next,
.close {
  margin:20px 10px 0; 
  display:inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide"><a id="1" class="showDetail">Slide1</a></div>
    <div class="slide"><a id="2" class="showDetail">Slide2</a></div>
    <div class="slide"><a id="3" class="showDetail">Slide3</a></div>
    <div class="slide"><a id="4" class="showDetail">Slide4</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <div class="slideDetail detail1">Slide1 - blurb</div>
    <div class="slideDetail detail2">Slide2 - blurb</div>
    <div class="slideDetail detail3">Slide3 - blurb</div>
    <div class="slideDetail detail4">Slide4 - blurb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideButtons"> 
    <a class="close">close x</a>
    <a class="previous">< Previous</a>
    <a class="next">Next ></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do appear to be binding the functions for the next and previous each time the details panel open. You can either move those functions out of the panel show or do this:

```
   $('.previous').off("click").on("click", function() {
```

as an example for each of those to unbind and rebind the scroll function.

Comment: Many thanks. The amount of time I've wasted on this! Doing what you suggested gets it working as expected.